# R plot legend with transparent background

Tags: r, plot, legend, alpha-transparency

How to R plot legend with transparent background when using `plot()` function ?

Comment: you can use `bty="n"` inside `legend`

Comment: Note also that `legend` accepts the bg argument, so that you can fill in the background with a different color if desired.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use: *bg="transparent"* in

```
legend()
```

Such as:

```
legend("right",bg="transparent",col=c(as.numeric(unique(df$group2))),cex=0.5)
```